# jquery UI datepicker is not showing up on html input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

[image]

The above input text or label doesn't seem to show the jQuery UI datepicker when click on either of it. I tried different combinations of solutions found here in SO and online. Not sure why none are working.

Html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>  

<label class="tmDtpicker">
    <input id="dtinput" class="hasDatepicker" type="text" name="Start" placeholder='10/05/2014' data-constraints="@NotEmpty @Required @Date" />
</label>
```

CSS code:

```
.tmDtpicker #dtinput {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 130px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}

.tmDtpicker:after {
    content:'\f073';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    cursor: text;
}
```

js code:

```
</body>
   //other scripts

<script>
    $(document).ready(            
          function () {
              $("#dtinput").datepicker({ showWeek: true, firstDay :1,                  
                  showOtherMonths: true,
                  selectOtherMonths: true,
                  minDate: '0d', dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
              });
          }
        );
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have included 2 `jquery-ui`.

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
...
```

Remove the first one.

```
...
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
...
```

For a side note, always include `jQuery` first then other libraries like `jqueryUI`

**Update**

Remove `class="hasDatepicker"` from the `input`.

Comment: I removed the above, but it doesn't seem to do a thing to the code.

Comment: @aspiring See the update, you need to remove this class `hasDatepicker`

Comment: That works I think, it has nothing to do with the different jquery libraries I used. I put them back, saved and run again, it is working after removing the class.